# How to compare vectors of different sizes in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have two vectors, one that contains information about series (ID, name, genre and numOfSeasons) and another which contains episodes of different series (ID, IDofEpisode, name, duration, rating, season). The first vector only contains around 4 series (with all of its information inside the vector) and the second one with more than 50 episodes of all 4 series (with all of its information inside the vector aswell). The ID of both vectors have the same number if they go together, for example:

`series(20110125, "Game of Thrones", "Drama", 8);`

`series(20170120, "Dark", "Mystery" ,2);`

`episodes(20110125, "20110125-S01E01", "Winter is coming", "1:02", 9.1 ,1);`

`episodes(20170120, "20170120-S02E01", "Beginnings and Endings", "0:53", 8.9, 2);`
and so on

What I need to do is to be able to compare both vectors by their ID number, my problem is that i'm not sure how to do that considering the size difference. If it is any help, these vectors are from different classes (Series and Episodes).

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "comparing the vectors"? If they have different size they dont compare equal for sure, but otherwise it is not clear what comparison you want to make

Comment: What do you mean by "vector"? Normally in C++ people use that term to mean `std::vector` but I guess that's not what you mean here, give that they seem to have different types of items in them (strings, integers and floating point numbers). Are these actually just `struct`s?

Comment: You should use map for series and multimap for episode using ID as key. then to get number of items of given Id you can use count function.

Comment: Can you give a simplified example of two such vectors, and show what you want the result of your comparison to be? I'm asking for a concrete example - not prose or vague terms. Like show the actual code you have so far. [example]

Comment: Please provide some [mre] in your question. We otherwise need to guess what is inside your brain, and that is difficult

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `compare both vectors by their ID number`. Obviously you want to compare ID numbers from one vector with ID numbers from the other vector, but what result do you want from that? What are you hoping to get from the comparison?

Answer (score 2):

> How to compare vectors of different sizes in C++

I guess you think of comparing two instances of the same type of [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) specifically. So two `std::vector<>` for some well defined and ordered [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type)  (it should be [*LessThanComparable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LessThanComparable)).

Comparing a `std::vector<int>` with a `std::vector<std::string>` makes no general sense (you need to specify what you want on paper).

You first need to **specify on paper your compare operations**. Should it define some [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Formal_definition)? Perhaps you want some [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), and the types of your vector components are comparable?

In that case, consider using [`std::lexicographical_compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare)

For more about C++, see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Perhaps read the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

A different approach would ensure that each instance of some of your superclass has a *unique* identifier (e.g. a serial number - or a [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) of them, or your class with `operator <` which implements an order - perhaps stored in some [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database)), and you'll then compare objects by their unique id.

You could also compare instances of some of your `class`-es by their address (e.g. using [`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof)). But the behavior of your program on many operating systems then becomes non-reproducible because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) (and stricto sensu, doing that is probably [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior); it does work in practice in most cases).

Maybe better or more suitable [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) could fit your needs. If you often compare many different sequences of thousands of integers that you know are totally ordered, you could consider representing each of such an [ascending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition) sequence by some `std::set<int>` and comparing such [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)-s might be cheaper. YMMV.

You definitely should consider writing your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html), to optimize the compare at *compile-time* and/or generating the C++ code comparing them using [metaprogramming](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) techniques. So generate boring C++ code like [SWIG](https://swig.org/) does. Read then for inspiration J.Pitrat's book [*Artificial Beings: the conscience of a conscious machine*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848211015) ISBN  978-1848211018

Answer (score 1):

Since you will be comparing the two collections only by their ID's then the size difference shouldn't be an issue. You can just access the first element that will be the ID and compare the two collections based on this.